# Android app doens't want to update information when refreshing it

Tags: android

Firstly, I'm sorry in advance that I cannot really structure my problem correctly, but basically I'm new to the android development and I have an exercise to create a Quiz game. The app consists of a class with Questions and a class QuestionRepository which contains in itself an arrayList with the questions.

**Questions class**
             package com.program.uni.quizgame;
             import java.util.Random;

```
  public class Questions {
     private String question;
     private String answer1;
     private String answer2;
     private String answer3;
  private String answer4;
  private int winningQuestion;


public Questions(String question, String answer1, String answer2, String answer3, String answer4, int winningQuestion) {
    this.question = question;
    this.answer1 = answer1;
    this.answer2 = answer2;
    this.answer3 = answer3;
    this.answer4 = answer4;
    this.winningQuestion = winningQuestion;
}

public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}

public void setQuestion(String question) {
    this.question = question;
}

public String getAnswer1() {
    return answer1;
}

public void setAnswer1(String answer1) {
    this.answer1 = answer1;
}

public String getAnswer2() {
    return answer2;
}

public void setAnswer2(String answer2) {
    this.answer2 = answer2;
}

public String getAnswer3() {
    return answer3;
}

public void setAnswer3(String answer3) {
    this.answer3 = answer3;
}

public String getAnswer4() {
    return answer4;
}

public void setAnswer4(String answer4) {
    this.answer4 = answer4;
}

public int getWinningQuestion() {
    return winningQuestion;
}

public void setWinningQuestion(int winningQuestion) {
    this.winningQuestion = winningQuestion;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return question;
}
```

}

**The questionsRepository class**

```
  import java.util.Random;
   import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class QuestionRepository {
     private Random randomGenerator;
      ArrayList<Questions>  myQuestions;

public QuestionRepository(ArrayList<Questions> myQuestions) {
    this.myQuestions = myQuestions;
    randomGenerator = new Random();
}

public Questions getRandomQuestion(){
    int index = randomGenerator.nextInt(myQuestions.size());
    Questions questions = myQuestions.get(index);
    return questions;
}
```

}

**Finally my main activity. Please excuse the hardcoded parts.**
     package com.program.uni.quizgame;

```
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.TextView;

   import org.w3c.dom.Text;

     import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     private Button button1;
     private Button button2;
     private Button button3;
     private Button button4;
     private QuestionRepository questionRepository;
     private TextView textView;
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       ArrayList<Questions> myArrayslist = new ArrayList<Questions>();


    myArrayslist.add(new Questions("What's 2+2? ", "4", "2", "1", "69", 4));
    myArrayslist.add(new Questions("What's 2+1? ", "1/2", "1", "4", "3", 3));
    myArrayslist.add(new Questions("What's 3+2? ", "0", "5", "6", "7", 5));

     questionRepository = new QuestionRepository(myArrayslist);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textForQuestions);
    Questions randomQuestion = questionRepository.getRandomQuestion();
    textView.setText(randomQuestion.getQuestion());
     button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
     button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
     button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
     button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    button1.setText(randomQuestion.getAnswer1());
    button2.setText(randomQuestion.getAnswer2());
    button3.setText(randomQuestion.getAnswer3());
    button4.setText(randomQuestion.getAnswer4());
    int answerToConvert = questionRepository.getRandomQuestion().getWinningQuestion();
     String convertedAnswer = Integer.toString(answerToConvert);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                   if(!button1.getText().equals(convertedAnswer)){
                       button1.setEnabled(false);
                   } else if(button1.getText().equals(convertedAnswer)){
                       textView.setText("Congratulations, the answer is: " + convertedAnswer);
                   }
        }
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if(!button2.getText().equals(convertedAnswer)){
                button2.setEnabled(false);
            } else if(button2.getText().equals(convertedAnswer)){
                textView.setText("Congratulations, the answer is: " + convertedAnswer);
            }
        }
    });

    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(!button3.getText().equals(convertedAnswer)){
                button3.setEnabled(false);
            } else if(button3.getText().equals(convertedAnswer)){
                textView.setText("Congratulations, the answer is: " + convertedAnswer);
            }
        }
    });

    button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(!button4.getText().equals(convertedAnswer)){
                button4.setEnabled(false);
            } else if(button4.getText().equals(convertedAnswer)){
                textView.setText("Congratulations, the answer is: " + convertedAnswer);
            }
        }
    });










}
```

}

So I want to get the answer to a particular question, in my case it's an int, but I convert it to String and compare that String with the getText(); for the buttons, which I have previously set to represent each of the answers. If the answer is the same I'll do something, if it's not I'll black out the button.

I'm getting an error saying that **convertedAnswer** needs to be final in order to be used in the OnclickListener. How do I tackle this problem. Any help would be appreciated. Feel free to bash me for my horrible coding, as I'm new. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to mark `convertedAnswer` as `final`.

`final String convertedAnswer = Integer.toString(answerToConvert);`

Comment: The thing is I don't want it to be final, as if I do so it will stop getting updated.

Comment: You're initializing `convertedAnswer` in `onCreate`, so it will only be scoped to `onCreate` which will be called once for your activity, so it would never be updated anyways?

Comment: So If I want it to be updated I need to initialize it outside of the onCreate, right? @Arcadian_Ghost

Comment: Yes, you would want to create a field for `convertedAnswer` in `MainActivity`. You can then initialize it however you want in `onCreate`, and update it later. From what I can tell you aren't attempting to update the value however, so making it a field on `MainActivity` doesn't make sense at this point (although I don't know your full design intention). And obviously, marking the field as `final` wouldn't allow you to update it later.

Comment: My design intention is everytime I launch the app another question to be loaded in with the respective answer. I guess since I'm not updating the `convertedAnswer` I cannot expect the program to run correctly

Comment: If you are restarting the app each time you want to show a different question, then you wouldn't need a field for `convertedAnswer`, you could leave it as a local variable scoped to `onCreate`, then passed into your `onClickListener`.

Answer (score 0):

Make `j` a field variable and don't make it final, that will solve your problem.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     private Button button1;
     private Button button2;
     private Button button3;
     private Button button4;
     private QuestionRepository questionRepository;
     private TextView textView;
     String convertedAnswer; //define it in here.
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```